# Custom shaped UISegmentedView-like Form in UIKit

Tags: swift, uiview, uikit, uisegmentedcontrol

I recently came across a fascinating design and I am interested in replicating it in UIKit. The design involves a non-rectangular form with a UISegmentedView-like component attached to it.

[image]

I am aware that UIKit allows us to create non-rectangular shapes using UIBezierPath and CAShapeLayer. We can define a custom shape with a UIBezierPath and then apply that path to a CAShapeLayer to mask our view. However, the element in the design appears to be a complex fusion of two elements, leading me to believe that a custom class extending from at least two UIKit classes might be required to achieve it.

I am wondering if I might be overthinking this. Is there a simpler way to re-create this design in UIKit?

Comment: Are you hoping to *animate* the "rounded-tab" shape at the top?

Comment: I was wondering how an experience developer would create it, the rounded tab at the top seems to be an UISegmentedControl, but appears to be fused with the form tab

Comment: Well, how to approach this depends on ***what you want to do***. Very easy to use a single bezier path to create the "tabbed card" shape... I'd say its unlikely the top is a `UISegmentedControl` ... rather, buttons (or labels with tap recognizers). Two views, one with the "tab" on the left and one with the "tab" on the right. Tap a button/label, and show/hide the respective views... or, a single view -- changing the bezier path and the visibility of the contents based on the selected state. Best bet is to start working on it.